# Interpolated attribute expression causes syntax error unrecognized expression in browserlink

Tags: angularjs, visual-studio-2013, browser-link

I thought I would check here first for confirmation, but also didn't know where to report the issue.

Has anyone else noticed that the following type of code causes syntax error in visual studio 2013's new browserlink?

```
<input id="cell_{{$index}}_1" ... />
```

This is occurring both in IE 11 and Chrome.

Thanks,

Comment: Your code didn't follow. please post.

Comment: edited, sorry for the omission.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like it's a reported issue (See here):

https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/814546/browserlink-throws-an-exception-when-using-angularjs-and-binding-in-an-attribute-browserlink-does-not-like-in-a-html-attribute

The official response from Microsoft:

This issue has been fixed in upcoming VS update.